# Incorrect date formatting

Tags: mysql

I am having problems with date formats, was trying many formatting solutions but non of them was working.

I do have table with dates and I am summing repeating dates:

```
SELECT 
    tt.time,
    DATE_FORMAT(tt.time, '%x-%v') AS time_label,
    SUM(value) AS value
FROM
    time_table tt
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tt.time, '%x-%v')
ORDER BY time ASC
```

[image]

As we can see it's formatting end year date as a new year date. [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) `%x` is saying

> Year for the week where Monday is the first day of the week. Used with %V
>    and for `%v`
>   Week where Monday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %X

Comment: That's correct as far as I remember. The first week of the year may start in the previous year. Please specify what is the result you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first week of the year 2020 started on Dec 30, 2019. See [Week Numbers for 2020](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020).

Therefore `2019-12-30 12:42:53` is being formatted correctly as `2020-01`.